# What's the name of the device I'm looking for

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I'm looking for a device which monitors a 3.3V line. When the line drops below, say, 2.7V, I would like it to switch power over to a battery backup (3V lithium coin cell.) It would also be good if it provided a logic signal to alert of the supply failure so the MCU in my project can switch over to a low power mode. It needs to be able to switch up to 120mA when the supply is high. What is the name of this device? I have a feeling it's quite common in applications like laptop computers.

Ideally it would have 5 pins: Vin main, Vin backup, GND, Vout, Logic out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power Management Controller / Power Management IC

The functionality your after would normally be part of a full system power management IC or a battery charging/management IC.

If all you need to implement is exactly what you asked for, a single FET with a low Drain <-> Source voltage drop and maybe a couple resistor to set the trip point are all thats required.

If you need to smoothly handle bounce, such as the bounce that occurs when you plug in a DC barrel jack, you can use a supervisor/reset controller designed to deal with bounce and use the reset output to trigger the FET.

Comment: That's a bit vague... I mean a voltage regulator is a power management IC.

Comment: +1 - That's what I would have called it.  Digikey apparently agrees with Thomas with [27 'PMIC' categories](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?lang=en&site=US&WT.z_homepage_link=hp_go_button&KeyWords=PMIC&x=0&y=0), but this one - [Power Supply Controllers](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Cat=2556707&k=PMIC) looks like it contains what he wants.

Comment: @ree: PMIC is an incredibly general term that encompasses virtually all ICs that are not strictly logic/digital or analog.  Taking a brief look at the "Power Supply Controllers" they generally appear to be specialized logic chips that don't actually handle/pass any power.

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem. They are sequencer IC's, not battery backup IC's. I'd hate to have to go to a multi chip solution as space is critical.

Comment: @Tho: What was the issue with having a diode from the battery to the supply line (no diode along the main supply)?  Li/MnO2 cells have an open voltage of 3.2-3.3 V, so the battery diode shouldn't conduct normally.

Comment: Well, I need to isolate my supplies. The switched voltage only needs to go to the MCU. There is also a DSP and LED on the board which would drain the battery pretty quick.

Comment: you need to use a multi-channel power management controller and just get it over with...

Comment: or pepper your board with diodes, like noted.

Answer (score 3):

Power Supervisor IC

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a Diode-OR'd power with the line voltage also going to a digital input pin to read the line voltage.

But there's probably a chip for that.

Comment: As mentioned in my previous question that wouldn't be suitable because diodes drop too much voltage. I'm looking for an IC to do this.

Comment: @Thomas O: How much current are you drawing at peak and when in standby, and what are the voltages?

Comment: Peak: 120mA, standby: 1µA, 3.3V.

Comment: Schottky diodes would only drop 0.3-0.4 V at 120 mA (36 mW), and less at lower currents.  Will your IC do better?

Comment: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#%24+1+5.0E-6+10.20027730826997+45+5.0+43%0Av+288+320+288+208+0+0+40.0+3.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0A172+288+128+256+128+0+6+2.7+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5+Voltage%0Ad+288+128+416+128+1+0.42%0Ar+416+208+416+320+0+25.0%0Aw+288+320+416+320+0%0Aw+416+208+416+128+0%0Ag+288+320+288+336+0%0Ad+288+208+416+208+1+0.42%0Ao+3+64+0+35+5.0+0.2+0+-1%0A

Comment: It needs to interface to 3.3V logic, so loosing .3V on the supply is not good.

Comment: A 220 Ω resistor will eliminate any ill effect from putting 3.3 V into a 3.0 V clamped chip.

Comment: On *every* IO? It's a bit of a hack and doesn't allow for high speed signalling due to input capacitance.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to replace [OR-ing diodes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6076/smallest-lithium-battery-backup/6080#6080)?  How about an [OR-ing controller](http://focus.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?family=analog&familyId=1644&uiTemplateId=NODE_STRY_PGE_T)?  Such devices are generally designed for much more current.

Maxim has some interesting [battery backup supervisors](http://www.maxim-ic.com/products/supervisors/battery_backup/).

Comment: Those require external fets, any with built in fets?

Comment: @Thomas: See update.  I'd also think some supercapacitor IC managers might work as well, but couldn't find any off-hand.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of measuring the output of your 3.3V regulator to find out when it's crashing due to low battery input, you should probably be measuring the battery voltage so that your battery doesn't get overdischarged. Done properly you can switch from one battery to another as the input to your 3.3V regulator without its output fluctuating below spec.  If switching to a smaller battery you'd probably want to reduce the load at the same time.

This question is basically the same:
[How do I design a device to automatically switch to the backup battery?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4012/how-do-i-design-a-device-to-automatically-switch-to-the-backup-battery)